# Getting a value from a df2 using the values from two columns of df1, using them as index. Same way as index(match(),match()) in Excel

Tags: r, indexing, match

I have df1 with columns for country and weight (integer); and df2, where there is a row for every weight (integer) and a column for every country, being the data in df2 the cost associated to every situation.

I have created two new columns at df1, as to get the positioin of every country's column and weight's row, such as:

```
df1$country.position <- match(df1$country,colnames(df2))
df1$weight.position <- match(df1$weight,rownames(df2))
```

And so I have the two new columns for the positions in df2. My next step was:

```
df1$cost <- df2[df1$weight.position,df1$country.position]
```

I actually get the correct row for weight, but it is always yielding the case for the same (apparently randomly chosen) country/column. I  don't know what else to do, as I went parallel ways for countries and weights.

To understand it better, what I am trying to do is similar to the combination index(match(),match()) in Excel.

```
df1:
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+
|  country  | weight | weight.position | country.position |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+
| france    |      2 |               2 |                3 |
| venezuela |      1 |               1 |                2 |
| spain     |      3 |               3 |                1 |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+


df2:
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+
| weight | spain | venezuela | france |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+
|      1 |  3.44 |      4.56 |   3.12 |
|      2 |  4.20 |      5.80 |   4.00 |
|      3 |  5.13 |      7.00 |   4.97 |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+

Result:
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------+
|  country  | weight | weight.position | country.position | cost |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------+
| france    |      2 |               2 |                3 | 4.00 |
| venezuela |      1 |               1 |                2 | 4.56 |
| spain     |      3 |               3 |                1 | 5.13 |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------+
```

Comment: Can you share sample of the data in `df1` and `df2`, as well as your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `df2[df1$weight.position,df1$country.position]` is that its selecting all the rows within df1$weight.position and all the columns within df1$country.position, not combinations of row+column.

Here's a different approach with dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(country = c("france", "venezuela", "spain"),
                  weight = c(2, 1, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(weight = c(1, 2, 3), 
                  spain = c(3.44, 4.2, 5.13), 
                  venezuela = c(4.56, 5.8, 7.0),
                  france = c(3.12, 4.0, 4.97))

df_long <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-weight, names_to = "country", values_to = "cost") 

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df_long , by = c("weight", "country"))


    country weight cost
1    france      2 4.00
2 venezuela      1 4.56
3     spain      3 5.13
```